# Force home page only to non-ssl

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I need to write an htaccess that only forces the home page to non-ssl

so if you are going to https: //www. 123.com or https://123.com it will redirect/force it to go to http: //www. 123.com or http://123.com.

I only want this change on the home page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a https box to test on but I think these rules should do what you want:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On 

# Only rewrite if using HTTPS and that we're on the index page, then redirect to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.[a-z]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule .+ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What happens? What is the URL (you can use a dummy domain name if you want I'm just interested in the structure).

Comment: it still loads the page over https://eosworldwide.com and does not forward/revert to non-ssl

Comment: does this have something to do with ssl priority over .htaccess?

Comment: If you check the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable, does the request end with index.php on *https://eosworldwide.com/*? Is it possible for you to check if the %{HTTPS} condition works, for example by adding **RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on** NEWLINE **RewriteRule ^/testtest$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,QSA,L]** - then visit https://eosworldwide.com/testtest and see if the redirect works

Comment: If I add /testtest with info you sent, 404 page comes up.

Comment: Ok, interesting. If you remove the **RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on** condition from the last rule. Does the /testtest redirect work? By the way I just remembered I doubt we need the **[L]** flag because we use the **[R]** flag so feel free to change *http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} **[R,QSA,L]*** to *http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} **[R,QSA]***

Comment: This did it: RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^$ http://eosworldwide.com/ [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^$ http://eosworldwide.com/ [L,R=301]